# Does a ball striking ground with different forces contradict Newton's Second law of Motion?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, gravity

The second law says that
$$F = ma$$
Let's assume that a ball is dropped and it strikes the ground with a force. And the process is repeated albeit from a greater height.
To calculate the force, we need two things, the mass m and the acceleration -g. The value changes slightly with change in height so we take into consideration the the value of g when it strikes the ground which comes out to be the same for both cases.
So as m and g are same for both, force should be the same as well. But we know that it is not. The ball dropped from a greater height strikes the ground with a higher force.

What is the flaw in my reasoning?

Comment: In the second case, there is greater deceleration when the ball strikes the ground, therefore greater force on the ground.

Comment: Already answered here https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/373476/357431

Comment: mg is the weight of the mass so the force it excerds when not moving.  In F=ma a ist the change of velocity per time, it depends on the velocity  and the time of impact. the time of impact is bigger, with a soft ball an shorter with a elastic ball, so a depends on the velocity of the ball  and the time it takes to stop it.

Comment: Have you drawn a free body diagram?

Comment: $F=F_g-mg=ma$ is the correct force balance.